# Add user to Remote Admin group on multiple hosts

Tags: powershell

I am using the following code to add a single user to the Admin group on multiple hosts.

```
param(
        [string] $Domain,
        [string] $UserName
    )

$ComputerListFile = "D:\Scripts\AddWindowsUser\ComputerList.txt"
$ComputerList = Get-Content $ComputerListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

foreach( $Computer in $ComputerList) {
    $Group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/Administrators,group"
    $User = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Domain/$UserName,user"
    $Group.Add($User.Path)
}
```

When I try to execute using the following command,

```
.\AddWindowsUser.ps1 -Domain "AD" -User "356989"
```

I get the following error,

```
distinguishedName : 
Path              : WinNT://computername.domain.global/Administrators,group

The following exception occurred while retrieving member "distinguishedName": "The network 
path was not found.
"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

What is the error here?

Answer (score 1):

I can propose you a different approach.

- Use `net localgroup` command to do it
- Run the `net localgroup` command using `Invoke-Command`
  on all computers.

  ```
  Invoke-Command -Computer $ComputerNames -Scriptblock {
      Param(
           $UserName,
          $DomainName
      )
      net localgroup administrators /add $Domain\$UserName
  } -ArgumentList $UserName,$DomainName
  ```